# Алгоритм Брезенхема для окружности

Tags: pascal, алгоритм, графика

[Алгоритм Брезенхема](http://www.opita.net/node/132). Помогите понять алгоритм.

Вот код:

```
Procedure Circleb(xc,yc,r:integer);
var x,y,d:integer;
procedure sim(x,y:integer);
begin
    putpixel(x+xc,y+yc,White);
    putpixel(x+xc,-y+yc,White);
    putpixel(-x+xc,-y+yc,White);
    putpixel(-x+xc,y+yc,White);
    putpixel(y+xc,x+yc,White);
    putpixel(y+xc,-x+yc,White);
    putpixel(-y+xc,-x+yc,White);
    putpixel(-y+xc,x+yc,White);
  end;
 begin
 d:=2-2*r;
 x:=0;
 y:=r;
 while(x <= y) do
   begin
    sim(x,y);
    if d<0  then d:=d+4*x+6  //Вопрос: что значит это вырыжение и как оно
    else begin               //получется? (d:=d+4*x+6)
     d:=d+4*(x-y)+10;        //И это выражение.
     dec(y)
    end;
    inc(x)
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: там же в статье вывод этих формул есть и обоснование.

Comment: Где? Я не вижу

Comment: [3. Что у него внутри][1]

[1]:http://www.codenet.ru/progr/video/alg/alg4.php#tth_sEc0.0.4

Comment: @Yura Ivanov А конкретно, какая строчка?

Comment: читайте все. d - это погрешность выбора того или иного пикселя. в зависимости от погрешности уменьшается или нет y. Описано довольно строгое математическое доказательство. если писать более подробно, то пришлось бы повторить вывод d, который там написан.